# Flot from array of struct

Tags: flot

in my CSV file, each line contains timeStamp and some values that I want to display as separated flot charts.

Flot expects array of pairs as [timeStamp , value]
but I have arra of struct [timeStamp, val1,val2, val3]

Is there a simple solution to use such struct in Flot? 
or that I must duplicate my timeStamp for each csv.column ? e.g. [time,val1], [time,val2] . . .

similiar question, with no answer - [Plotting multiple datasets in Flot from a multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869101/plotting-multiple-datasets-in-flot-from-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Could you give more details on what the structure of your data is and how you want to display it in your chart? There are some possible ways to have more then one value for one timestamp (for example bars with start and end / top and bottom values or [errorbars](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/series-errorbars/index.html)).

Comment: e.g. The values can be [timeStamp, innerTemprature, outerTemprature, innerHumidity, outerHumidity] 

I want to display them as simple-line-charts, on one grid. 
If I have both Temprature and Humidity, I use multi-yaxes.

Comment: Then you should split you data into multiple data series by looping over it.

Comment: duplicating the timeStamps for each serie ?!

Comment: Yes. (comment must be 15 characters long)